# unable to login into admin in Django unit tests but can login in dev server?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-testing

I am facing a strange problem. I am able to login to admin by running 
`python manage.py runserver` and giving the correct credentials

but my test fails, if I give the exact same credentials that I used in development server.
I am following this [TTD tutorial](http://www.realpython.com/blog/python/django-1-6-test-driven-development/#.U3EJLK1dWrh).

Here is the code:

```
class AdminTest(LiveServerTestCase):
fixtures = ['admin.json']
def setUp(self):
    self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    self.browser.maximize_window()

def tearDown(self):
    self.browser.quit()

def test_admin_site(self):    
    # user opens web browser, navigates to admin page
    self.browser.get(self.live_server_url + '/admin/')
    body = self.browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
    self.assertIn('Django administration', body.text)
    # users types in username and passwords and presses enter
    username_field = self.browser.find_element_by_name('username')
    username_field.send_keys('admin')
    password_field = self.browser.find_element_by_name('password')
    password_field.send_keys('admin')
    password_field.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    time.sleep(3)
    # login credentials are correct, and the user is redirected to the main admin page
    body = self.browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
    self.assertIn('Site administration', body.text)
```

The test fails with error message:

```
AssertionError: 'Site administration' not found in u'Django administration\nPlease enter the correct username and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.\nUsername:\nPassword:\n '
```

PS: I use `Postgres` for `backend database`. All the tutorials I see uses 'sqlite3'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're starting from a fresh test database so your admin user does not exist yet.  You need to create it manually in the test case.

This should work:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
User.objects.create_superuser('admin', 'admin@mysite.com', 'admin')
```

Comment: woow! this worked. but if you glance the tutorial above, it seem to work without this. does it have to do with database type?

Comment: and why fixtures did not help here?

Comment: @brainstorm Are you sure that the fixtures were actually loaded during your test?  If so, then maybe the password hash is incorrect (special character, wrong hash algo, etc).  Can't tell at first glance....

Comment: @brainstorm  On a side note, I generally stay away from fixtures in tests because of the overhead it takes to keep them up to date.  Creating them in code helps catch a lot of minor issues that I believe more than makes up for the speed you gain from the fixtures themselves.